# How do I use a prebuilt virtual machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

I downloaded prebuilt virtual machines of Windows 7 and XP. I'm trying to run them in VMware, but I don't know how to use a prebuilt VM. How do I get them to work?

Comment: What are the file extensions of the VMs you downloaded or where did you get them? What did you try so far and what has not worked?

Answer (score 0):

I can give some advice for oracle's virtualbox, but not vmware since I haven't used it.

So, in the download should be a virtual hard drive file.  Open up the peripheral manager CD's, hard drives, etc.  Make a new virtual hard drive, or, if one already exists, use that one.  Change the mounted medium to the virtual hard drive that you downloaded.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that with a prebuilt virtual machine, on VMWare Workstation, I just imported it and it worked perfectly. I am having WiFi issues, but that's a different question.